# Breezejs sending over multiple entities

Tags: php, api, breeze

I'm using [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com/) w/ a PHP backend API and am curious if two or more entities are being created at the same time that have a relationship with each other - if they all get sent to the server at the same time when the request is sent to the server - how do you:

1. Know which item needs to be created first for the relationship constraints to succeed
2. If one entity is created successfully, but there is some problem w/ the other entity (ie: 400, 401, 500, etc...)  what would be an appropriate response to send back in the response?

This is what my current request looks like:

[image: Current Request]

Is there a better way to break these up and if so - does breeze (with its knowledge of metadata) know to send requests in the appropriate order?